# How do I set the screen background to image in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do I change the background to image in this code am not using any .Kv file. I want to set the screen background to an image but am only seeing the ones with .kv file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import Floatlayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.label import Label 


class LandingScreen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

         self.score=0

        # put whatever pos_hint value you want.          
        self.add_widget(Label(text='SCORE: ' + str(score), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5)))
        self.btn1=Button(text='button1 ', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b1))
        self.btn2=Button(text='button2', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), 
        on_press=self.click_b2))


            
        self.add_widget(self.btn1)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)

        def click_b1(self, instance):
             
             score +=10
        def click_b2(self, instance):
             score += 10
       
class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to do in `kv`, but you can do it without `kv` by adding this code to the `__init__()` method of `LandingScreen`:

```
    with self.canvas.before:
        self.bg = Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size, source='background.png')
```

And you will also need to adjust the size of the background when the size of `LandingScreen` changes. To do this add this method to `LandingScreen`:

```
def on_size(self, *args):
    self.bg.size = self.size
```