# Kivy layout background issues with self.pos

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I had a label background image in kv language, but redid it in python to add HoverBehavior property for my labels.

Was:

```
<RockLayout>
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        source: 'data/images/gui_elements/rock_label.png'
```

Became:

```
class RockLayout(FloatLayout, HoverBehavior):  # BoxLayout
def __init__(self, widget, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    widget.size_hint = (.8, .8)
    widget.pos_hint = ({'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .52})
    self.add_widget(widget)
    with self.canvas.before:
        Rectangle(source='data/images/gui_elements/rock_label.png', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

def on_enter(self, *args):
    self.canvas.before.clear()
    with self.canvas.before:
        Rectangle(source='data/images/gui_elements/rock_label_hover.png', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

def on_leave(self, *args):
    self.canvas.before.clear()
    with self.canvas.before:
        Rectangle(source='data/images/gui_elements/rock_label.png', pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

This caused the *self.pos* in *canvas.before* doesn't updates at the moment of initialization and *self.pos* equal to 0. When i resize the window the position of the images doesn't change.
How to declare background image in python, not in .kv language?

[It's happens now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WKeC.jpg)

[self.pos isn't updated when I resize the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAKpV.png)

[What I need to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmJmq.jpg)

How to use kivy layuot background image in python correctly?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62774766/how-do-i-set-the-screen-background-to-image-in-kivy/62776083#62776083) which also applies to `pos`.

Comment: Thank you very much!) It's works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def on_size(self, *args):
        self.bg.size = self.size
        self.bg.pos = self.pos
```

Comment: Welcome, I see you found your solution. It seems you found the solution from the link John posted in a comment. If so, please close this question or mark as duplicate of that other question... there are millions of posts in the site and we need to help curating the content.